# Adding info to tables in Parse.com (Android)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to add information to the Parse.com class, ***[Registration Class in Parse.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkqfl.png)***, from an android app.  The information needs to be linked with the specific user which is logged in on the app.

Here is the ***[Android App Registration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0f3T.png)***.

Thanks in advanced.

*P.S. I am able to register a user using the android app.*

Comment: What's the problem? What code are you using to attempt to do this?

Comment: @zgc7009 I was  trying to do it this way:  

`ParseObject NextOfKin = new ParseObject();  
NextOfKin.put(usernametxt, usernametxt);  
NextOfKin.put(usernametxt, usernametxt);  
NextOfKin.saveInBackground(); `  

But I get the error **_The constructor ParseObject() is not visible_**

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide check out saving an object. You can't utilize the default constructor, you need to pass the class name in the constructor itself so Parse knows where to point.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit lost with the default constructor :/

Comment: You see how you are saying `ParseObject NextOfKin = new ParseObject();`? Well according to the docs, that won't work. You have to pass the class name in the constructor. So it would be (assuming the class name in parse is "NextOfKin") `ParseObject NextOfKin = new ParseObject("NextOfKin");`. Also, take a look into Java naming conventions to see the standards in regards to naming variables, methods, classes, etc.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a million :)